# Firebase GoogleSignIn failing for release builds served via Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using Firebase SDK to integrate Google SignIn in my Android App. 
Below is my code to check if authentication was successful or not. When I distribute release APK via Play store, authentication fails with error code number 10. The very same release APK works fine when installed using adb install or Crahlytics Beta or by just clicking on the "apk" file on device.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int , resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {

     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        var task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            var account: GoogleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            abslytics!!.logException("google_signin_failed", e)
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Toast.makeText(this@GoogleSignInActivity, "Google sign in failed: " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For your Play Store release, did you enable [Google Play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#google-play-app-signing)?  If so, did you add the generated SHA-1 fingerprint to your project settings,  download a new google-service.json, and rebuild?

Comment: @BobSnyder: Yes, I did enable Google Play App signing ad updated generated SHA-1/google-service.json in project.

Answer (score 2):

Add SHA-1 certificate fingerprint & SHA-256 certificate fingerprint from  google play console to your firebase console. To get these two key go to your google play console > Release Managment > App signing > App signing certificate.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for this answer and a reminder of the signing process. "Step 4: Register your app signing key with API Providers" at this link provides more information:  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en